# Using type annotations at package level

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, type-hinting

I want to use annotations to have better auto-completion in IDEs, and maybe later type testing in automated tests. But how can you add type annotations to many methods without introducing a lot of extra code?

For example, imagine that you have a big code base which uses the Django framework, including about 200 methods with a `request` argument; adding the type annotations 200 times would bloat the code.

My current idea is to include type annotations at the package level: in `setup.py` (or somewhere else). I define a rule that says *"every time the variable `request` gets used, it is of type `django.http.HttpRequest`"*. For edge cases where the variable with the name `request` points to a different type, explicit annotations should be done, but there are very few of these.

How can this be implemented? Are there other ways to achieve the overall goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, this sounds like a use-case for *stub files* which, as described in [**`PEP 484`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files):

> Stub files are files containing type hints that are only for use by the type checker, not at runtime.

Stub files pretty much fulfill your requirement of separating code from type annotations thereby avoiding the bloating and obfuscating effect of complex type hints. They have a prefix of `.pyi` and, if a type checker implemented by an `IDE` that wants to conform to `PEP 484`, must always be examined by the type checker if they exist.

They essentially consist of the annotated function signatures with a body containing a single ellipsis `...`

---

One way you could go about this is using a helper function to write out your `.pyi`, or, at least, the bulk of it. There's probably many ways to do this and which is the best is probably another question altogether.

As an example of a way to do this, I'll write out a way to annotate every function in the `inspect` module that has a parameter named `object` and doesn't start with an underscore. I'm typing this specific module since I'll also be using it for identifying functions and grabbing their signatures.

From the `inspect` module, I'll be using the [**`getmembers`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers), [**`isfunction`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) and [**`signature`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) functions.

```
# gets members of inspect module {member_name: member_type} dict.
members = getmembers(inspect)  

# loop through members
for name, type in members:

    # grab functions that don't start with an underscore  
    if isfunction(type) and not name.startswith('_'):

        # grab its signature and
        # check if it has a parameter named object
        sig = signature(type)  
        if 'object' in sig.parameters:

            # add the annotation to the object parameter
            param = sig.parameter['object']
            s = sig.replace(parameters = [param.replace(annotation="object")])

            # here you normally write to .pyi file
            print('def {0} {1}: ...'.format(name, s))
```

This logic could be extended to `method`s, other parameter types and so on. 
Also, **an important note**, the `.pyi` file should have the same name as the module you're annotating, so in this case it should be `inspect.pyi`.

For now, this simply prints out all functions which have a parameter named `object` with the 'annotation' (`object`) we supplied:

```
def findsource(object:'object'): ...
def formatannotationrelativeto(object:'object'): ...
def getabsfile(object:'object'): ...
def getcomments(object:'object'): ...
def getdoc(object:'object'): ...
def getfile(object:'object'): ...
def getmembers(object:'object'): ...
def getmodule(object:'object'): ...
def getsource(object:'object'): ...
# .. and so on..
```

most production ready checkers will read this `.pyi` file and provide the functionality you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. You get the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) (untested):

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

class RequireHttpRequest():
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        require_http_request = view_kwargs.get('require_http_request', True)
        if require_http_request and type(h) != HttpRequest:
            raise SomeException
        return None
```

By default, this middleware would affect all URLs. For the few URLs for which you do not want to check the type of `request`, add a parameter in the corresponding lines of urls.py:

```
url(r'^foo/$', views.your_view, require_http_request=False)
```

and put the specific annotations in the definition of `my_view()`.

Comment: I guess my question was too vague. I added this: I want annotations to have better auto completion in IDEs. Maybe (later) type testing in automated tests.